# What can you use to remove hair gel?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

The hair gel is called "lets Jam Gel". It says it uses micro emulsion technology.
What chemicals can you use to break it down or undo the bonds?

I'm trying to get it out of my head. I washed my hair with T sal and cut my hair off but it still grows back patchy and easy to style like it has gel in it. I think it may be in the epidermis or even dermis by now.

ingredients: 42692 SS11 - Aqua / Water Isocteth-20 Paraffinum Liquidum / Mineral oil Glycerin Oleth-2 Propylene Glycol Parfum / fragrance Sorbic Acid Methylparaben DMDM Hydantoin Ethylparaben Limonene Hydroxycitronellal Geraniol Amyl cinnamal Linalool Simethicone CI 19140 / Yellow 5 CI 14700 / Red 4, CI 172200 / Red 3. F.I.L D45949/1

Comment: It would help if you added what you're trying to accomplish, and, if possible, an ingredients list off the container. Are you trying to wash it out of your hair, or out of your carpet, for example? And is it [this stuff](http://www.softsheen-carson.com/_us/_en/lets-jam/lets-jam-custard.htm)?

Comment: ingredients: 42692 SS11 - Aqua / Water Isocteth-20 Paraffinum Liquidum / Mineral oil Glycerin Oleth-2 Propylene Glycol Parfum / fragrance Sorbic Acid Methylparaben DMDM Hydantoin Ethylparaben Limonene Hydroxycitronellal Geraniol Amyl cinnamal Linalool Simethicone CI 19140 / Yellow 5 CI 14700 / Red 4, CI 172200 / Red 3. F.I.L D45949/1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unintended side effects of a product that are better addressed by a physician.

Comment: More likely by consulting a hairdressing professional.

Answer (score 2):

Yikes.

As far as I'm aware, a thorough application of ordinary soap or washing-up liquid should be able to wash this off using the normal [surfactant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfactant) processes (binding to organic components with lipophilic regions of the molecule). If you're experiencing long-lived after-effects (say, more than a week maybe), you might want to see a doctor -- it's not impossible you could have had some sort of allergic reaction. Oh, and if you're going to wash hair with soap or washing-up liquid, I'd suggest using conditioner afterwards, to reduce the long-term damage incurred by stripping the natural fatty acids and oils off.

I'm not a medical professional or a tricologist, though, so please don't take this as Official Medical Advice.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but I don't think it worked. The soap really dried out my hair. I think I got it out of my hair but I have a feeling the gel is still stuck under my scalp.